# Typescript how to define nested objects with different keys

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have two classes `Foo` and `bar`, each class has an attribute called `fields` such as

```js
// Foo
fields = {
    id: {
        type: 'number',
        display: 'ID'
    },
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        display: 'Name'
    }
    // ...
}

// Bar
fields = {
    version: {
        type: 'number',
        display: 'Version'
    },
    valid: {
        type: 'boolean',
        display: 'Valid'
    }
    // ...
}
```

Fields in these classes have different keys, but each key value has the same type with `type` and `display`. Is there a way to define a type or interface for `fields`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t need to limit what the keys can be called you can define a `Record` with keys of `string` and values of an object with `type` and `display` fields:

```js
type MyType = {
  fields: Record<string, {
    type: 'boolean' | 'number' | 'string';
    display: string;
  }>;
};

interface MyInterface {
  fields: Record<string, {
    type: 'boolean' | 'number' | 'string';
    display: string;
  }>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `Record` is exactly what I have been looking for.